# Devise map login page for multiple urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use devise for authentication. I have an admin user to play with the application. Is it possible to map the urls '/login' and '/admin' to the same login form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Add the following to your routes.rb file, assuming your devise model is called 'admin':

```
devise_scope :admin do
  get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  get 'admin' => 'devise/sessions#new'
end
```

The normal '/admins/sign_in' route will still be available as well.